# Request parameters have amp; in param name

Tags: symfony, parameters, request, twig

I'm generating a path to my controller in a twig template with the path function, and adding additional parameters. the first parameter comes in fine but the other parameters have amp; added to their names.

this is the twig statement:

```
location.href = "{{ path('export_report', { 'fileId': 'datatable_export_excel', 'country': 'eu', 'countries': ['BE, NL'] }) }}";
```

with as result this url:

```
location.href = "/reports/export?fileId=datatable_export_excel&amp;country=eu&amp;countries%5B0%5D=BE,%20NL";
```

In my symfony backend the request query data is the following:

```
fileId = "datatable_export_excel"
amp;country = "eu"
amp;countries = [0 => "BE, NL"]
```

How do i encode or decode this proper? and where?

Comment: Use the filter `raw`

Comment: You do not need to use raw with the path function.  If I had to guess, you are doing {{ location.href }} somewhere in your template.  This is what needs to be changed to {{ location.href | raw }} to avoid html escaping.

Comment: Same thing in another location right?